# Vulnerability in NestJS 8.4.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nestjs

Recently, when I run `npm audit` in my npm package, I receive the following error:

[image: npm audit report]

The problem seems to be in the dicer package which is a very popular package used by NestJS.

I searched the web for possible solutions but can't find any fixes. Has anyone been able to fix this yet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: note that `dicer` isn't used by nestjs. `@nestjs/platform-express` depends on `multer`, which depends on `busboy`, which uses `dicer`. Maybe [this PR](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/9686) would fix that? I'm unsure

Comment: so as long as you don't use `multer`-related features from `@nestjs/platform-express`, you don't need to worry

Comment: Is there a way to unplug multer from my nest application to avoid those security errors for my devops?

Comment: I guess you can use [NPM v8 overrides feature](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) (or Yarn resolutions feat). At least this is what I've been using to avoiding installing `@nuxtjs/opencollective` package - which is a hard dep of `@nestjs/core` here: https://gitlab.com/micalevisk/nestjs-slim-typescript-starter/-/blob/main/package.json (but I believe that might not work on windows)

With Yarn I've been using a 'noop' package like so under `resolutions` on `package.json`: `"@nuxtjs/opencollective": "npm:@codemeistre/noop"`

Comment: and then you could run `npm ls multer` to see if it succeeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that NestJS has fixed it by removing dicer from their packages. I fixed the issue just by deleting the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 3):

> Has anyone been able to fix this yet?

No, or at least not in a published form. A fix for the dicer bug is not available. [The URL in the picture](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wm7h-9275-46v2) of the text you included says that.

NPM is offering to downgrade nestjs/core to a version that doesn't depend on it. That will fix the issue (although probably create others).

Looking at the Github page for dice shows [a bug report](https://github.com/mscdex/dicer/issues/30) where you can get upto date information about the state of any fix.

Answer (score 1):

Found a temporary solution until it will be fixed by devs, by using [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) - [all honors to @hiagodotme](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/9686#issuecomment-1146116245)

1. Delete package-lock.json & node_modules
2. Provide overrides for multer in package.json ( npm 8.x )

```
  "overrides": {
        "multer": "^1.4.4-lts.1"
    },
```

3. Re-install modules